Authentication problem with Auth Query - PGBouncer
I am using PG Version 14.3 and Bouncer 1.20v. I am trying to use auth query for authentication and connection via bouncer. I created a auth user as 'pgbouncer' and it's password is encrypted as scram-sha-256. All the user password is hashed as scram-sha-256 since it is a default password encryption method in 14.3v. I specified auth type as scram-sha-256 and tried to connect to PG via bouncer. But it is not working. I am getting the following error;
cannot do SCRAM authentication: password is SCRAM secret but client authentication did not provide SCRAM keys
I tried some of the methods to resolve the issue. As a result, I came to know, if the auth user password in userlist.txt file is either plain text or md5 the postgres connection is working otherwise It is not working. I reffered some of the web documents and I noticed this,
https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/508
I am not sure if this issue still persists in the 1.20v. Can anyone please help me with this issue?
I referred this: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pgbouncer-authentication-made-easy/ to setup the pgbouncer auth query
Contents of pgbouncer.ini:
[databases]
 postgres = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres
 sasdb = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test auth_user=pgbouncer
 [pgbouncer]
 listen_port = 9000
 auth_file = <path to userlist.txt>
 auth_query = select p_user, p_password from lookup($1)
 auth_type = scram-sha-256
 listen_addr = *
 logfile = <path to pgbouncer.log>
 pidfile = <path to pgbouncer.pid>
 max_user_connections = 100
 pool_mode = transaction
 ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits


How exactly did you set up pgBouncer?

This is working as expected.  SCRAM does not offer/suffer from "pass the hash" vulnerabilities, and so your setup cannot work.  You will have to choose a different authentication configuration for the auth user.  Like peer, maybe.

@LaurenzAlbe I used some of the online guides to setup this.

I source compiled bouncer and created bouncer.ini and userlist.txt file
I created the auth user and populated the same in the pgbouncer.ini (Added the contents in the question)
I added auth user and its scram-sha-256 password in userlist.txt file
Started bouncer and tried to connect to postgres via bouncer


@jjanes SCRAM does not offer/suffer from "pass the hash" vulnerabilities, and so your setup cannot work.
if it is not any pass the hash vulnerability, Can you please explain why it is not working?

In order to work, it would need to "exploit" a pass-the-hash vulnerability.  Since there isn't one there to be exploited for SCRAM, it can't work.  userlist.txt would need to have the actual password, not just the SCRAM hash of the password, in order to authenticate to the server with SCRAM.
